# serve and excel template for download in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, excel, download, xlsx, serve

I have an AngularJs application and I am importing data from excel sheet. Now I have a Template which needs to be used for importing.

Please help me how do I **serve the excel template for download** using Angularjs.

Till now: I have a folder in the application called **excel-template** and in the UI i have provided **`<a href="excel-template/excel-template.xlsx">Download</a>`**.
It downloads the files but when I open it, it says that it is corrupted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the anchor tag to serve excel template for download. Make sure the path is correct.

`<a target="_self" href="excel-templates/XYZ.xlsx" download="XYZ.xlsx"><span>Download Template</span></a>`